# Find the day given date and number of days

Tags: vb.net

Am looking a function that would aid me to auto detect due date when duration period number is entered in duration textbox.Am having challenge since all the months do not end with same date number i.e. 31 as some end on 30.

NOTE: The function should be able to automatically calculate up to next year if lets say user inputs 3 while in November 2018 its means the duration period will go up January 2019
See the picture below
[image]

```
Dim start_date As Date = dtpStart.Value
Dim totalDays As Integer = 3 * 30
Dim ts As TimeSpan = start_date.Add(totalDays)
Dim end_date As Date = ts
```

I have tried the above but its giving me an error "value of type integer can not be converted to system.TimeSpan."

Comment: i have tried the following but its giving me an error "value of type integer can not be converted to system.TimeSpan"
Dim start_date As Date = dtpStart.Value
        Dim totalDays As Integer = 3 * 30
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = start_date.Add(totalDays)
        Dim end_date As Date = ts

Comment: Please don't post multiline code in comments. You should be posting the code you tried in your question, so please edit your question and add the relevant code, formatted correctly.

Comment: That said, the solution is simple and you should have found it yourself because you should have read the documentation for the `DateTime` type by now.  You simply call `AddDays` on a `DateTime` containing your start date and it will return another `DateTime` containing the correct date.

Comment: -1. A simple Google search solves this. And also the official docs are pretty straightforward too: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: Also, it Is not clear what you are asking. The title of the question talks about adding days, but the question says that adding 3 to November should give January. If that's what you need there is an `AddMonths` function on `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, if a user enters 3 you want to advance 3 times 30 days later from the start_date.

```
Dim start_date = dtpStart.Value
Dim end_date = start_date.AddDays(3* 30)
```

In terms of a function, you could have:

```
private function AddDays(Byval start_date as Date, Byval amount as integer) as Date
    Dim end_date = start_date.AddDays(amount)
    return end_date
end function
```

The usage would be:

```
Dim new_date = AddDays(dtpStart.Value, 3*30)
```